# How to produce a `ArrayBuffer` from `bytes` using `js_of_ocaml`

Tags: javascript, string, ocaml, arraybuffer, js-of-ocaml

I am building a JavaScript library that is implemented in Ocaml and compiled to JavaScript using [`js_of_ocaml`](https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/).

One of my Ocaml function returns a `string` with binary data. How can I expose that using `js_of_ocaml` as a `ArrayBuffer`?

Answer (score 7):

When you compile to javascript, manipulating binary data in `string`s is extremely bug prone!

The underlying reason is questionable choice of `js_of_ocaml`:
Because javascript strings are encoded in UTF16 whereas OCaml ones are (implicitly) encoded in UTF8, `js_of_ocaml` tries to navigate in between the 2. Therefore, when it encounters a "character" whose code is > 127, `js_of_ocaml` converts it which is a disaster if it is, in fact, raw binary data!

The solution is to manipulate `bigstring`s instead of `string`s.
Bigstrings are `(char, Bigarray.int8_unsigned_elt, Bigarray.c_layout)
  Bigarray.Array1.t` in raw OCaml but more and more libraries aliases them.
Especially, they are `Typed_array.​Bigstring.t` in `js_of_ocaml` (where you can see functions to convert from and to `ArrayBuffer`)

If your function does work by magic on string once compiled in javascript, there are translation function in between bigstrings and strings in several places. 
For example the bigstring library: http://c-cube.github.io/ocaml-bigstring/ but these functions are also available in `Lwt_bytes` of [lwt](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/4.1.0/api/Lwt_bytes)

You can see an other question on the same subject (including ways to manipulate OCaml string in javascript while not touching them at all using `gen_js_api`) at
https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/handling-binary-data-in-ocaml-and-javascript/1519

Comment: Thanks! So far it all seems to work using `string`, somehow…

Comment: @JoachimBreitner, you might not run into issues as long as binary strings are only passed from JS to ML, whereas the conversion pitfall would be in the other direction.